# Find string between tags not working

Tags: string, lua, lua-patterns

I have this string

```
str="[COLOR r;255|g;255|b;0]  1 | Someoneelse       | 8000     |    0 |    0 |    0[/COLOR][ENTER]  2 | Expendables  | 4000     |    0 |    0 |    0[ENTER]  3 | Extra   | 2000     |    0 |    0 |    0[ENTER]  4 | Extraordinry  | 0        |    0 |    0 |    0"
```

and I want to return all between `[COLOR r;255|g;255|b;0]` and `[/COLOR]`

I try it but, it doesn't work

```
print(string.find(str,"[COLOR r;255|g;255|b;0](.-)[/COLOR]"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
print(string.match(str,"%[COLOR r;255|g;255|b;0%](.-)%[/COLOR%]"))
```

Note that `[`,`]` are magic characters, so they need to be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

iam solved it

```
string.gfind(str,"%[COLOR r;255|g;255|b;0](.-)%[/COLOR]")()
```